# Is there a way to specify specific repository classes to include in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have several repository interfaces defined in one package. However, I want to configure them separately, in groups, to use with respective database setup. `@EnableMongoRepositories` seems to only consider packages as unit of grouping. Is there a way to achieve multiple repository configuration without having to break up my interfaces into multiple packages?

Comment: Have you considered grouping by profiles via `@Profile`?

Comment: You can, of course, use Spring profiles or conditional enabling using auto configure, but I'm not sure why are you trying to invent a new way of separating classes that you say belong to separate groups. Just use different packages and move on.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yes, it's easy to just create separate package and be done with it. However, sometimes, we follow specific project conventions so that people involved can readily guess the function of each component just by looking at their structure.

Comment: @fg78nc I haven't really used profiles in Spring before, but I can't really see how that can help. I need all the repositories to run in any environment or configuration profile, but I need them use separate database configurations. Say there are repositories that need to access local database, then there are those that need to access one on a remote server.

Comment: @PsychoPunch You assign different configuration(repository) to each profile

Comment: @PsychoPunch So using different packages, which is a static configuration, is confusing to your team but using Spring profiles, which arbitrarily changes the behavior at runtime, isn't? Your definition of code maintenance is clearly different than mine; I'll get my coat.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I'm not here to argue with you about that anyway. Take care on your way out.

Comment: @fg78nc well, that still won't let me pick which particular repository interfaces in one specific package I want to apply specific repository configuration, will it? If I have, say, `BookRepository` and `AuthorRepository` in `com.sample.repository`, can I specify through profiles that I want `BookRepository` to use book database at localhost, and `AuthorRepository` to use author database at some remote host?

Comment: @PsychoPunch Reply does not fit in the comment, so please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`@EnableMongoRepositories(value = {"com.your.repos.base.package"}, includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {MySingleRepository.class})})`

Answer (score 0):

Link each profile to distinct property source (.properties file)

```
@Configuration
    public class AppConfig
    {
        @Configuration
        @Profile("dev")
        @PropertySource("classpath:localdb.properties")
        static class LocalDb
        { }

        @Configuration
        @Profile("prod")
        @PropertySource({"classpath:remotedb.properties"})
        static class RemoteDB
        {}
```

Define active profile via VM args

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

or programatically

```
SpringApplication.setAdditionalProfiles(..)
//or
ConfigurableEnvironment environment = this.applicationContext.getEnvironment();
environment.setActiveProfiles("dev");

// or in case of WebAppContext via web.xml 
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value> // or prod
 </context-param>

//or in case of WebAppContext if using servlet 3.1+ container set programatically
servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
```